# Updating my application across thousands of nodes. What are the standard tools/procedures?

Tags: apt, update, rsync

Are there any standard practice/procedures/tools to perform a software update (OTA) of my c++ application across thousands of battery powered IoT nodes.

I don't want to reinvent something, and wondering if a proven/standard tool or solution already exits. Ideally something that would be power fail-safe.

Edit:

I would like to make a custom smart-speaker (Alexa or Google Home) type devices, powered by battery, using RPi Zero W

Comment: Where comes a Raspberry Pi to play? Do you have thousands of battery powered RasPis?

Comment: I don't have them today. I would like to make smart speaker (Alexa) type devices, powered by battery, using RPi Zero W

Comment: you might want to look into dev-ops tools such as puppet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The professional OTA updaters include: Mender, rauc, swupdate

These are power fail safe, as they do an "A/B" update. Two images: A and B, where A is the current running image stays flashed, until the new B image is confirmed to be flashed in the OTA partition.

The following presentation gives a good overview of differences between pushing debugging images, ci images, and production images:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCDZVjHHC6o